# Cant install pycurl in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycurl

I have python 3.9 installed on windows and for some reason, it cannot install pycurl. Actually, I want to install wfuzz but it requires pycurl.

I ran - `pip install pycurl`
error -

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz (222 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\priya\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\priya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dlfl9k8g\\pycurl_1de5cab79d3e476a8871140d654794b2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\priya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dlfl9k8g\\pycurl_1de5cab79d3e476a8871140d654794b2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-97a16f4f'
         cwd: C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dlfl9k8g\pycurl_1de5cab79d3e476a8871140d654794b2\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: you must provide a working curl installation like the message says

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycurl%5D+Please+specify+%22--curl-dir%22

Comment: Downgrade to Python 3.8 64-bit and do `pip install pycurl==7.43.0.5` — you should get a precompiled wheel from https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/7.43.0.5/#files

Comment: Also see https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl